# How to accept Ethereum payments on a membership video streaming site?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, web3-providers, payments, hosting

What is the best way, or are there any regulated payment merchants besides BitPay, to accept recurring subscription fees in Ethereum, for example, on a video streaming site?

Or would it be better to have a self-destroying smart contract set up for members to buy into, and then re-purchase after that contract expires?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a very nice question!

There are many ways for recurring payments if you want a fully decentralized way Superfluid is the way to do so! Their concept is actually mind blowing from my view

https://www.superfluid.finance/home
https://youtu.be/SfPxY8GMJT4

Comment: which blockchain are they